# How to get desired json formatted data in c#

Tags: c#, json

In controller code, I have data in json format

```
data = {
1: {assetId:1,status:true},
2: {}
}
```

I used hash table for the above format..

I want to get the data in this format

```
data = [
{
    1: {assetId:1,status:true,tmestamp:05}
},
{
    1: {assetId:1,status:true,tmestamp:06}
}
]
```

please suggest what data structure should i use to achieve this in C#.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Deserialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) technique to extract the data.